# MongoDB node native driver creating duplicate documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm getting a duplicate document when using the mongodb-native-driver to save an update to a document. My first call to `save()` correctly creates the document and adds a _id with an ObjectID value. A second call creates a new document with a text _id of the original ObjectID. For example I end up with:

```
> db.people.find()
{ "firstname" : "Fred", "lastname" : "Flintstone", "_id" : ObjectId("52e55737ae49620000fd894e") }
{ "firstname" : "Fred", "lastname" : "Flintstone with a change", "_id" : "52e55737ae49620000fd894e" }
```

My first call correctly created Fred Flinstone. A second call that added " with a change" to the lastname, created a second document.

I'm using MongoDB 2.4.8 and mongo-native-driver 1.3.23.

Here is my NodeJS/Express endpoint:

```
app.post("/contacts", function (req, res) {
  console.log("POST /contacts, req.body: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));

  db.collection("people").save(req.body, function (err, inserted) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      console.dir("Successfully inserted/updated: " + JSON.stringify(inserted));
      res.send(inserted);
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the runtime log messages:

```
POST /contacts, req.body: {"firstname":"Fred","lastname":"Flintstone"}
'Successfully inserted/updated: {"firstname":"Fred","lastname":"Flintstone","_id":"52e55737ae49620000fd894e"}'
POST /contacts, req.body: {"firstname":"Fred","lastname":"Flintstone with a change","_id":"52e55737ae49620000fd894e"}
'Successfully inserted/updated: 1'
```

Why doesn't my second update the existing record? Does the driver not cast the _id value to an ObjectID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are posting back the 2nd time contains a field named "_id", and it's a string. That is the problem.

Look at the document, what the [save method](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#save) does is a "Simple full document replacement function". I don't use this function quit often so here's what I guess. The function use the _id field to find the document and then replace the full document with what you provided. However, what you provided is a string _id. Apparently it doesn't equal to the ObjectId. I think you should wrap it to an ObjectId before passing to the function.

Besides, the save method is not recommended according to the document. you should use [update](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#update) (maybe with upsert option) instead

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know why a second document is created, but why don't you use the **update** function (maybe with the **upsert** operator)?

An example for the update operation:

```
var query = { '_id': '52e55737ae49620000fd894e' };

db.collection('people').findOne(query, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (!doc) {
        return db.close();
    }

    doc['lastname'] = 'Flintstone with a change';

    db.collection('people').update(query, doc, function (err, updated) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.dir('Successfully updated ' + updated + ' document!');

        return db.close();
    });
});
```

And now with the upsert operator:

```
var query = { '_id': '52e55737ae49620000fd894e' };
var operator = { '$set': { 'lastname': 'Flintstone with a change' } };
var options = { 'upsert': true };

db.collection('people').update(query, operator, options, function (err, upserted) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.dir('Successfully upserted ' + upserted + ' document!');

    return db.close();
});
```

The difference is that the upsert operator will update the document if it exist, otherwise it will create a new one. When using the upsert operator you should keep in mind that this operation can be underspecified. That means if your query does not contain enough information to identify a single document, a new document will be inserted.

Comment: Thank you for your well thought out alternative to the save(). The answer to why I was getting a duplicate (except for the _id) document is as explained in the accepted answer. I have switched to using an update as you show except I'm passing in the full document as a parameter to the update. The docs say "If the <update> document contains only field:value expressions, then the update() method replaces the matching document with the <update> document. The update() method does not replace the _id value."